# Image got error 500?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is kind of strange, I never have problem when I do development in Visual Studio 2010.

Or after publish to my local iis7 and connect to the site directly with network ip 192.168.x.x. (using IE)

But when I access from DNS redirect, using some domain name.. Sometime some of the image will not display (from iis7 log it got error 500)...  Then if I right click the image and choose Show Image to reload the image, it will show up properly again.

```
From Server2008 IIS7 Log
    2011-04-15 14:07:56 173.32.2.83 GET /MyASPProgram/Styles/title_bar_bg.png - 80 - 173.239.186.98 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 500 0 0 109
```

I wonder if that's a problem with the iis7 setting? But is strange to work fine when access the network... Or it is just the DNS redirect problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using?

I bet this is the [classic double hop issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx).

Comment: I wonder if that's related? That Double-Hop Issue sounds like is an issue will occurs all the time if my application has it, but the image is only got error 500 sometime and only some of the image of the page (they are all locate in same folder in iis7).  And I guess you mean the authentication in IIS7? I have Anonymous Authentication enabled and selected IIS_User.

Comment: I know that we had that issue with a ASP.NET MVC project on IIS7 and it was pretty random. We were using Windows Authentication though. Of course, I cannot guarantee that your issue is the same but we had the exact same symptoms. My answer was mostly meant as a hint towards what I think is the right direction.

Comment: hmmm I guess I will try setting Windows Authentication to try it out... Is it the method A in the page linked to? I added     <identity impersonate="true"/>
<authentication mode="Windows">  in my Web.config, but where to set the security mechanism part?

Comment: I suggest you Google the "IIS double hop issue" a bit to determine if it even can happen with Anonymous Auth. You cannot use Windows auth on a public website as that would require visitors to apply credentials they don't have. As I said - it was a pointer and a bit of a best bet.